# Localization for new Files in older Project breaks App

Tags: ios, localization, xcode4.2

Good evening

I want to add a new year, a new volume as plist-file to my existing app. The app is localized for 4 languages, so the new file has to be localized also. The languages were "English", "German", "French" and "Italian".

But when I do this, Xcode creates a directory "de.lproj" next to the existing "German.lproj", same behaviour for French and Italian, but not English. The older localized files are now in a directory "German.lproj", the newly generated plist in a folder called "de.lproj".

Then the app will no longer recognize the localized strings, exept the english version.

How can I add a new localized file to this project without breaking the rest?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem like this:

1. Make a backup of each localized file (`plist` and `strings` files) in the Finder and collect them in a folder for each language.
2. In Xcode, remove every localization for these files so that the only remaining language is `English`.
3. In Finder, delete the old `lproj` directories in the project folder except `English.lproj`.
4. In Xcode, add the formerly deleted localizations for each file. Copy the contents of the files into the newly generated localized files.

Maybe this can help somebody.

Comment: how do you get an `.lproj` folder? i dont even have those, and i did the whole "add language" thing in xcode

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Localization Suite](http://www.loc-suite.org/) to manage your translations. This way, you can let loc-suite to scan changes in your original .plist file and tell you which ones are translated and which ones are not. Loc-suite can also update your localized .plist file and remove dead entries.

This question is slightly off topic at stackoverflow though.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the old localized files where not recognized.